# How to build a custom image gallery in an admin form in magento2?

Tags: admin, module, magento2, extensions, image-upload

I'm in the process of building a custom module  to best implement the image management portion.What I want is this: 
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question, add what you already did, what doesn't work as expected and where you stuck. At the moment it reads like "I have no clue, please give me code".

Comment: @xanka please post your answer here